# Adding Elements in an array from ascending index element + descending index element

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

if the array is,
i = index value

```
array[50]={i(50) + i(1), i(49) + i(2), i(48) + i(3) .... i(1) + i(50)}
```

So every instance the array addition first index element is from 50 to 1 and the second index element is from 1 to 50.

How can I implement this in any way?

This is not homework. this is for my current project where I come across this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: To clarify, if `A = {5, 6, 25, 3}`, `i(25)` is `2`? I.e., `i(n)` is the index of the value `n` in array `A`?

Comment: no i mean if i take your array `A = {5, 6, 25, 3, 5, 9}` then the function should add like `A = {9+5, 5+6, 3+25}` and so on with every element in an array.

Comment: OK. What have you tried to accomplish this, and where specifically are you stuck? This would normally be implemented as a single `for` loop. Accessing the array elements is straightforward. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service; you need to demonstrate that you've tried something and are stuck with a specific problem.

Comment: I havent tried any code yet, i was writing the algorithm for this project for the documentation and stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
int[] a = {5, 6, 25, 2, 3, 5, 9};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(insideOutSum(a)));
```

Prints

```
[14, 11, 28, 4, 28, 11, 14]
```

For odd length arrays, it adds the middle element to itself.

```
public static int[] insideOutSum(int[] array) {
   int len = array.length;
   int[] result = new int[len];
   for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      result[i] = array[i] + array[len - i - 1];
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont need the code but but thanks i got it